# how to use $geoNear with LINQ in monogdb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, iqueryable

I upgraded from mongoDB C# driver 1.11 to 2.5.0 and I am no longer able to execute $geoNear while using LINQ.

From what I can tell, LINQ creates an aggregate query and $geoNear can not be in an aggregate query unless it's the first stage.
How can I combine $geoNear stage with any IQueryable? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
//valid Bson example that work in aggregate query
new BsonDocument
        {
            {"$geoNear", new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"near", new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {"type", "Point"},
                            {"coordinates", new BsonArray(new[] {45.73, 72.81})}
                        }
                    },
                    { "maxDistance", 100},
                    {"distanceField", "Calculated"},
                    {"spherical", true}
                }
            }
        };

 class Entity
    {
        public IList<Coordinates> Locations { get; set; }
        public int NumField { get; set; }
        public double Calculated { get; set; }
    }
```

Fyi, the reason why I'm working with IQueryable is because I don't want a coupling with my db to perform queries on mongoDB.

The previous code was:

```
private IQueryable<T> GetBsonRangeQuery(IQueryable<T> result) {
  BsonDocument coordinatesBson = Query.Near(
    fieldName,
    GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(45.73, 72.81)),
    100,
  true).ToBsonDocument();
  BsonDocument existingFilterBson = ((MongoQueryable<T>) result).GetMongoQuery()
    .ToBsonDocument();
  BsonDocument combined = existingFilterBson.AddRange(coordinatesBson);
  return GetInitializedMongoCollection().AsQueryable().Where(
    q => new QueryDocument(combined).Inject());
}
```

Comment: did you ever resolve this - I am facing a similar issue

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat no :(